# Find "a" so that 99*a=1a1

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

(This is my very first question here! :-) )
So I encountered this fun problem yesterday and am feeling like sharing it with you. I almost solved it with the help of my computer but I guess there is a way to solve it without.

So the question is: find all the integer $a$ so that $a*99$ is equal to $1a1$. (The same number "$a$" between two 1)

This is what I've done so far (spoiler alert if you want to solve it all by yourself):

---

I quickly converted this equation into this one: $89*a -1 =10^n$ with $n$ equals to the number of numbers in $a$ plus one.

Then comes $a=(10^n +1)/89$

So now the problem is equivalent to finding the n so that $10^n +1$ can be divided by $89$. One can notice maybe that $89$ is a prime number. Fermat theorem gives us : $10^{88} -1 =0 [mod 89]$ but this doesn't seem to help :/

Conceptually speaking, I find difficult to convert those two ideas mathematically: 
-How searching integers solutions differs from searching any solutions.
-How to use the fact that n is actually the number of numbers in $a$ plus one.

Hope you find the problem interesting and that some very bright solutions will come to your mind :-)

NB: using a computer, I have found some n that verify the equation but this is cheating somehow...

Comment: **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: What does $1a1$ mean here?

Comment: I explained between parenthesis what it means but maybe I was not clear enough. If "a" is 333 for instance, 1a1 would be 13331.

Comment: Really nice first question :) You can make your math formulas more readable with MathJax. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You need to find the smallest $n$ such that $10^n=1\mod 89$ such $n\mid 88$(n divides $88$). If such $n$ is divisible by $2$ then $10^{n/2}=-1\mod 89$ and $n/2$ is the smallest such $n$. otherwise the congruence $10^k=-1\mod 89$ has no solutions.

Comment: @botond thanks for the tutorial.

Comment: @sagar Chand, I actually tried a bunch of values for n so that 10^n+1 can be divided by 89. Then I computed "a" which was a proper solution (and not a fraction), the smallest solution is a very large number btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The observation that $10^{88}\equiv1\pmod{89}$ is *very* useful.

If $a$ is an $n$-digit number, the equation can be rewritten as
$$
99a=10^n+10a+1
$$
and so
$$
a=\frac{10^n+1}{89}
$$
so we need $10^n\equiv-1\pmod{89}$.

By Euler-Fermat, $10^{88}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$. Let's try and find the order of $10$ modulo $89$. We have $10^2\equiv11\pmod{89}$, $10^4\equiv32\pmod{89}$ and $10^{11}\equiv55\pmod{89}$, so $10^{44}\equiv1\pmod{89}$, but $10^{22}\equiv88\equiv-1\pmod{89}$. There's no need to look at $10^8$.

So the order is $44$ and we have also found a solution to $10^n\equiv-1\pmod{89}$, namely $n=22$.

Suppose $10^m\equiv-1\pmod{89}$; then $10^m\equiv10^{22}$, so $10^{m-22}\equiv1\pmod{89}$ and therefore $m\equiv22\pmod{44}$.

The solutions are the positive integers of the form $22+44k$.

The smallest solution is
$$
\frac{10^{22}+1}{89}=112359550561797752809
$$
The next solution is
$$
\frac{10^{66}+1}{89}=
11235955056179775280898876404494382022471910112359550561797752809
$$

Comment: Interestingly, the solutions are *very* close to sums $\sigma_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{n-k}F_n$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number: $$\tfrac1{89}\left(10^{22}+1\right)-\sigma_{21}=2113\qquad\tfrac1{89}\left(10^{66}+1\right)-\sigma_{65}=3314006522814$$ both *tiny* relative errors. Even better, it appears that $$\tfrac1{89}\left(10^{22}+1\right)=\left\lceil\frac{\sigma_{21+p}}{10^p}\right\rceil\qquad \tfrac1{89}\left(10^{66}+1\right)=\left\lceil\frac{\sigma_{65+q}}{10^q}\right\rceil$$ for $p\geq 5$ and $q\geq 17$. I feel like I'm missing an obvious connection.

Comment: @Blue Quite interesting indeed.

Comment: Whoops ... My definition of $\sigma_n$ should use "$F_k$", not "$F_n$".

Comment: With the related sum $\sigma_\star:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k}F_k = .11235955\ldots$ (omitting the leading $0$ on purpose), the recurrence $F_n+F_{n+1}=F_{n+2}$ makes clear why $99\sigma_\star=100\sigma_\star - 1\sigma_\star=11.1235955\ldots$ would have a digit string (without a decimal point) that is the concatenation of $1$ with $\sigma_\star$'s digit string (without a decimal point). So, maybe it's not surprising that the Fibonacci sums $\sigma_n$ enter into the "finitized" problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I don't understand why there is no need to look at 10^8 and why 10^¹¹ =55 imply 10^44=1 (I don't understand the "so"). Could you explain ? :-)

Comment: I just noticed the solutions are of the form: [(a-1)(10^24-a)]*a. Where "*" stands for repeating multiple times the expression on the left hand side and "a" being the smallest solution. I find it fascinating as if there was some wizardry involved here. Anyone else fascinated by this ? Any deep explanation about why this is happening? :-)

Comment: Made a mistake in my expression, it should read: ([(a-1)(10^23-10a)]*)a with the conventions unchanged.